# The correct way to save and query values from a join table in JDO?

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus

I have a Google App Engine web application where I'm using JDO to communicate with a Cloud SQL instance. In my database I have a table "User" and a table "Entity". Any user should be able to "like" one or more entities. So i have created a join table with userID and entityID as composite primary key.

I'm new to all this and I'm wondering how I should approach this with regards to saving and loading of the "likes". When saving a like I would just send the userID and the entityID to the server and store it directly in the join table. When loading, I figured I'd just do a join, but it seems difficult using JDOQL. I've read about M-N-relationship in JDO and wonder if I should model my entity classes with the @Join annotation instead and have a list in both User and in Entity.

It's not clear to me yet how all this works. For fetching, I guess lazy loading is the correct way. So if I understand correctly, when I want to retrieve a list of users that have liked an entity, I can just load the Entity-object and then call getUsers() on the entity while still within the transaction and it will fetch the users mapped in the join table?
If I update an existing Entity with null or empty list for Users, won't any existing relations in the join table then be deleted?

Comment: Design your model first, how it should be O-O, then think about persisting it. Is it simply a user can have multiple entities? or is it a user can have multiple entities and you want to store extra info alongside the relationship? JDO simply allows you to persist it or retrieve it, and shouldn't impact to any great degree on your O-O design.

Comment: A user can have multiple entities and an entity can have multiple users. Both Entity and User have main info in their respective tables. The relation is in a separate join table. When fetching User I normally do not want to fetch the list of related entities. But sometimes I will make a call to the server requesting all entities related to a given user. Normally without JDO I would just write a simple query with the given userID but I'm not sure how to do this correctly the O-O way